# Access to other localserver ip addresses through internet ip

Tags: iis

I'm writting a php based script for a company with a local server. Inside local ips can access eachother through 192.168.20.XX and some of these XX domains have web scripts.

We already have an static ip address which connect us to an ip address in localserver from internet. for example we can access 192.168.20.7 in local server through 12.34.567.89 internet ipv4.

how can i access other ips in local server through that ip? I'm trying to load some forms from ex.192.168.20.3 into 192.168.20.7

using iframe won't work as 192.168.20.3 is not known in internet, but just in local server. how to do it?

[image]

Comment: In general people run a reverse proxy on the system that is configured with the external IP-address . A reverse proxy can inspect the incoming request ,  parse the URI and forward the request the correct different back-end server. Each of the backend servers can access the others directly without going through the reverse proxy

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @HermanB, I found the answer with reverse proxy and [this link](https://docs.microfocus.com/OMi/10.62/Content/OMi/AdminGuide/Hardening/RevProxy_IIS.htm) helped me to configure it in IIS.